# How to preserve ADS (alternate data stream) in a Powershell script when transferring it over the Internet?

Tags: powershell, ads

I have a Powershell script that uses ADS to store credentials. When run on local computer or VMs accessible via RDP, everything is smooth. But when the script is uploaded somewhere for further download, upon download it keeps telling that it has no credentials stored.

I have tried making a *.zip / *.rar of it, no imrpovement so far. It behaves the same.

Is there any way to ensure ADS will still be in place after a user downloads the script from the Web?

Comment: You can't, ADS' are managed through references in the master file table on the NTFS filesystem in question

Comment: In WIkipedia, I managed to find information about ADS support in different file systems. It is not only NTFS that supports it. Some Linux file systems support it, too. Is ADS non-persistant across different FS?

Comment: Sure, but when you upload the file, your browser actually only read the contents of the `:$DATA` stream, not the NTFS object itself. So even though the target filesystem may support ADS, they'll disappear in transit unless you migrate directly (physically) from NTFS to another ADS-aware filesystem